# Tissue Deformation Simulation using FEM

Tags: numerical-methods, simulation, finite-element-method

I need to simulate `tissue deformation` using FEM.

Is it advisable to represent the object as a `triangle mesh` or a `tetrahedron mesh` ?

Please explain which approach would be better ?

Comment: It might help to write down the model, or at least the key equation of the model. I can tell you that you may need to be concerned with being able to quickly re-mesh your domain, since it sounds like you might have a free boundary problem.

Comment: You will probably reach more people working with FEM by asking at [scicomp.se]. That said, your question looks strange: triangle mesh is 2D, while tetrahedron mesh is 3D. Do you know if you are working in 2 or 3 dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the type of tissue. For a *thin* surface-like tissue (such as skin, perhaps)? a two-dimensional reduced model of the tissue using triangular elements (and a reduced formulation of the physics, such as Kirchhoff-Love plate theory) makes a lot of sense, as trying to simulate the full cross-section is a waste of computational resources.

For volumetric tissue, you will of course need to use three-dimensional elements; the decision there is not between triangles and tetrahedra, but between tetrahedra and hexahedra (generalized cubes). As a broad generalization, the latter is usually preferred for elasticity using low-order elements due to locking artifacts that can arise when using tetrahedra.